# how i can hide/show my div with change text on button

Tags: jquery

I am try to my div open with toggle and also change text on button.
my jquery code is below:

```
$(".open").click(function(){
        if($(this).text()=== "open"){
            $(this).text("close");
        }
        else{
            $(this).text("open");
        }
        $("div").show(300);
    });
```

and html is:

```
<button class="open">open</button>
<div style="display:none;">test box</div>
```

please help me how to show/hide my div and also change text on button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case just change `$("div").toggle(300);` instead of `$("div").show(300);` it will work.

```js
$(".open").click(function(){
        if($(this).text()=== "open"){
            $(this).text("close");
        }
        else{
            $(this).text("open");           
        }
         $("div").toggle(300);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="open">open</button>
<div style="display:none;">test box</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Mr Sathish your solution is also good and ease to learn.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text-function)** or **[`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html-function)** with callback function to toggle text and **[`toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)** for showing and hiding the div.

```js
$(".open").click(function() {
  $(this).text(function(i, v) { return v == "open" ? "close" : "open"; });
  $("div").toggle(300);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="open">open</button>
<div style="display:none;">test box</div>
```

Comment: this is good and worked and thanks Mr. Pranav but i want more ease method do u have any other idea.